# Is there a way to pass the webdriver instance from one class to another in c# selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I've been searching for a while and can't seem to find anything on c# about this, only java and other languages. Does anyone know how/if it is possible and is able to provide a simple example or point me the documentation available for me to read?

Very thankful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly pass the driver instance via constructor like this;

```cs
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var driver = new ChromeDriver();

        var instance = new AnotherClass(driver);

        instance.DoSomething();

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    private readonly IWebDriver _driver;

    public AnotherClass(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.facebook.com/");  
    }
}
```

Or you can store your driver in a property and make your main class static, so you can access it from any other class.

Comment: I seem to be able to do this on the same file, but what I was trying to go for is doing this on different files (use the same driver on script1.cs and then pass it to script2.cs)

Comment: @TugaInVegas, it doesn't matter if it's on the same file or not. Imagine that Program class is on the script1.cs and AnotherClass is on the script2.cs.

Comment: Ok, so do I have to import or call the other class somehow right? Sorry for the noobie questions, but I was requested to do some c# selenium stuff really fast and I'm trying to get my hold on it.

Comment: Yup! You can access to other classes from other files.